# Bounding derivatives of solution of an ODE

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

For a given $h$, suppose $f$ be the solution of the equation with $f(0)=0$
$$f'(x)-f(x)=h(x)-\int_0^\infty h(t)e^{-t}dt \tag{1}$$.

I want to bound the second derivative $|f''(x)|$. I realized that there are two directions I can proceed.
Clearly a solution is given by
$$f(x)=-e^{x}\int_x^\infty \left[h(y)-\left(\int_0^\infty h(t)e^{-t}dt\right)\right]e^{-y} dy$$
We can differentiate this twice to get.
$$f''(x)=h'(x)-e^{x}\int_x^\infty \left[h(y)-\left(\int_0^\infty h(t)e^{-t}dt\right)\right]e^{-y} dy+h(x)-\int_0^\infty h(t)e^{-t}dt$$
Another way could be to differentiate $(1)$
to get
$$f''(x)-f'(x)=h'(x) \tag{2}$$
The solution is given by
$$f'(x)=-e^{x}\int_x^\infty h'(y)e^{-y} dy$$
Therefore
$$|f'(x)|=\left|-e^{x}\int_x^\infty h'(y)e^{-y} dy\right|\leq \|h'\|$$
where $\|\cdot\|$ is the infinity norm.
And then from $(2)$,
$$|f''(x)|\leq 2\|h'\|$$
The two method seems to give two different answers. Can anyone please figure out where I am making the mistake?

Comment: What is the bound for $|f''(x)|$ that you obtain using the first method?

Comment: it was a complicated expression involving both $h$ and $h'$

Comment: Without seeing it it's impossible to say what was your mistake.

Comment: I have added it.

Comment: I suspect that you are failing to realize that the derivative of
$$
f(x)=-e^{x}\int_x^\infty \left[h(y)-\int_0^\infty h(t)e^{-t}dt\right]e^{-y}\, dy 
$$
is equal to
$$
f'(x)=-e^{x}\int_x^\infty h'(y)e^{-y}\, dy. 
$$

Comment: Sorrry if I am missing something, isn't the derivative $$f'(x)=h(x)-\int_0^\infty h(t)e^{-t}dt-e^{-x}\int_x^\infty[h(y)-\int_0^\infty h(t)e^{-t}dt]e^{-y}dy?$$

Comment: Notice that $f(x)$ can be rewritten as
$$
f(x)=-e^{x}\int_x^\infty h(y)\,e^{-y}\, dy + H,
$$
where $H:=\int_0^\infty h(y)\,e^{-y}\, dy$. Hence
$$
f'(x)=-e^{x}\int_x^\infty h(y)\,e^{-y}\, dy+h(x).
$$
On the other hand, integrating by parts your expression for $f'(x)$, we obtain
\begin{align}
-e^{x}\int_x^\infty h'(y)e^{-y}\, dy&=-e^x\left\{h(y)\,e^{-y}\bigg|_x^{\infty}+\int_x^{\infty}h(y)\,e^{-y}\,dy \right\} \\
&=h(x)-e^{x}\int_x^\infty h(y)e^{-y}\, dy.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks! Also does this mean that the $k-th$ derivative $$f^k(x)=-e^x\int_x^\infty h^k(y)e^{-y}dy?$$

Comment: Just a heads up for future posts: you can use `\left` and `\right` to make delimiters like parentheses, bars and brackets match the size of their content, and `\| \cdot \|` ($\| \cdot \|$, $\| u \|_{L^2}$) looks better for norms than just double bars.